# Error after adding an alias in global .gitconfig

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

I've added a line in my `.gitconfig` file on Windows:

```
[alias]
hist = log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h [%ad]%C(reset) | %s%d %C(green)(%cr)%C(reset) by %C(blue)%an%C(reset)" --graph --all --decorate --date=short
```

This code works fine if I use it from the git command line (like `git log --pretty=...`). But when I use alias, I get this error:

```
$git hist
fatal: |: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.
```

As I understand, the problem is in the "|" symbol. It is interpreted by command line as a path. Should I isolate it somehow, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes:

```
[alias]
hist = log --pretty=format:\"%C(yellow)%h [%ad]%C(reset) | %s%d %C(green)(%cr)%C(reset) by %C(blue)%an%C(reset)\" --graph --all --decorate --date=short
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to set the alias so it will work: (should be on single line)

```
git config --global alias.hist 'log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h [%ad]%C(reset) | %s%d %C(green)(%cr)%C(reset) by %C(blue)%an%C(reset)" --graph --all --decorate --date=short'
```

#### Break down and explain each part:

```
# set the alias at global level (name: hist)
git config --global alias.hist 

# start (and end) the alias content with the '
'log --pretty=format:"..." --graph --all --decorate --date=short'
```